# Signed vs. unsigned values for counting in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, int, size-t

So I have within a program an ordinary for loop through a vector of objects (objects that are of a type I defined, if that is relevant):

```
for(int k = 0; k < objects.size(); k++){ ... }
```

...and when I compile, I get this warning:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

This makes sense, since I think `size()` for a vector returns a `size_t`. But why would it matter? Isn't a certain number of elements (or even memory chunks) an integer that you can count? More importantly, since my program has multiple such loops and happens to segfault a lot, could this be part of it?

Comment: Another point of the warning is that if the signed value is (rightfully) negative, when it is converted to an unsigned type, the result tends to be very large, so the comparison may not have the outcome the programmer expects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem arises when `object.size()` returns a value that is *greater than the maximum representable value of `k`*. Since `k` is signed, it has only half the maximum value compared to a `size_t`<sup>1</sup>.

Now, this may not happen in your particular application (on a typical 32-bit system, that would be upwards of two billion objects in your collection), but it's always a good idea to use the correct types.

<sup>1. Pre-emptive rebuttal: Yes, this is only true for machines using typical two's-complement arithmetic, and for machines where `int` and `size_t` are represented using the same number of bits.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Well answered, already, but I'll add my S/0.02: The "correct" way to do this is:

```
for (typename std::vector<MyObject>::size_type i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Only aspiring language lawyers would write that, and even they are likely to stop reading before they get to the good stuff.

With C++11 you can take advantage of `decltype`:

```
for (decltype(object.size()) i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Or you can take advantage of `auto`:

```
for (auto i = object.size() - object.size(); i < object.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

Or you can just use `size_t`, but you still might have doubts about overflow, since `vector<MyObject>`'s size_type might be larger than size_t. (It isn't, but there are no guarantees):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < object.size(); ++i) { ... }
```

So what's an honest programmer to do?

The absolutely easiest solution is the one which STL has been promoting since the beginning. Except that in the beginning, it was also a pain to write:

```
for (typename std::vector<MyObject>::iterator_type it = object.begin(); it != object.end(); ++it) { ... }
```

Now, C++11 actually does help you. You have some very nice alternatives, starting with the simple:

```
for (auto it = object.begin(); it != object.end(); ++it) { ... }
```

But it gets even better (drumroll, please)...:

```
for (auto& val : object) { ... }
```

And that's the one I'd use.

---

Edited to add:

Cory Nelson, in a comment, points out that it is also possible to cache the result of object.end() with:

```
for (auto it = object.begin(), end = object.end(); it != end; ++it) { ... }
```

It turns out that the code generated by the `for (var : object)` syntax is very similar to that proposed by Cory Nelson. (So I'd encourage him and you to just use the latter.)

However, that has subtly different semantics from the other ones, including the iteration which was the subject of the original post. If you're modifying the container during the iteration in a way that changes its size, then you have to think things through very carefully. Disaster is highly likely.

The only way to iterate a vector which might get modified during the iteration is to use integer indices, as in the original post. Other containers are more forgiving. You can iterate an STL map with a loop which calls object.end() on each iteration, and (as far as I know) it will work even in the face of insertions and deletions, but don't try that with an unordered_map, or a vector. It does work with a deque if you always push at the end and pop at the front, which is convenient if you're using the deque as the queue in a breadth-first walk; I'm not sure if you can get away with popping the deque at the back.

There really should be a simple summary somewhere of the effect by container type of container modifications on iterators and element pointers (which are not always the same as iterators), since this is all specified by the standard, but I've never run into it anywhere. If you find one, let me know.

Comment: You missed `for(auto it = object.begin(), end = object.end(); it != end; ++it) { ... }` in case you don't want to call end() every iteration, which is good for compilers not supporting range for :)

Comment: @CoryNelson, yes, that's what `for (auto& val : object)` translates into. However, for most STL containers, maybe all of them, there's essentially no cost to doing object.end(). (For vectors, in particular, iterators are just pointers and end() is a trivial accessor.)

Comment: As an interesting note, for VC++ at least, vector's iterators have not been pointers under any circumstance for quite a while. They do of course optimize down to be equivalent, though!

Comment: @CoryNelson: interesting. So are they something other than a class whose only data member is a pointer? And what benefit does that provide? (In the gnu libstdc++, they are not pointers if there is an appropriate Alloc trait, which might be necessary for non-standard Allocators, but normally they're just typedef'd through a long chain of typedefs to a T*.)

Comment: @rici: In your last suggestion, would it be possible also to get a common integer counter for displaying the round number, or is that impossible (except by creating a separate loop counter)?

Comment: @arc_lupus: you'll need to add the loop counter yourself.

Answer (score 3):

in most cases it doesn't matter until you hit the point that your vector contains more elements than a signed int can represent.

Answer (score 2):

Important warnings may be lost in the stream of warnings about signed/unsigned comparisions for loop variables. And even some signed/unsigned comparision warnings are important! So, get rid of the unimportant warnings by defining a size function, like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>    // ptrdiff_t
#include <utility>     // std::begin, std::end

typedef ptrdiff_t Size;
typedef Size Index;

template< class Type >
Size nElements( Type const& c )
{
    using std::begin;  using std::end;
    return end( c ) - begin( c );
}
```

Then you can just write e.g.

```
for( int i = 0;  i < nElements( v );  ++i ) { ... }
```

Alternatively, *use iterators*, e.g.

```
for( auto it = begin( v );  it != end( v );  ++it ) { ... }
```

And/or use the C++11 range based `for` loop,

```
for( auto const& elem : v ) { ... }
```

Anyway, getting a clean compile, at the highest practical warning level, is important in order to get rid of those segfaults and other bugs.

Another area you should look at for that, is C style casts: get rid of 'em! ;-)